# react-grid-layout : render grid line in grid unit instead of pixels

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I currently render my grid line using pure css, click this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-grass-hz2xc?file=/src/styles.css) for my codesandbox. But this is not accurate as this grid is being render in pixels, not grid unit.

my css

```
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 3000px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(#ccc 0 1px, transparent 1px 100%),
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc 0 1px, transparent 1px 100%);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.react-grid-layout {
  background: none !important;
}
```

Is there any way to render the grid line so when my grid item is being render, it will reflect accurately.

For example, if i define w:2, h:4, x:0, y:0 my grid item will fit nicely.

Below image shows that I have import my style.css
[image: To those who say they cant see my style.css]

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but it suggested me about `background-image`.

To thank me to leave my answer to your question.
Adjust the parameters `background-size` as follows.

```
.gridContainer {
  background-image: ...;
  /** 
  * - 10px -> grid spacing  (px)
  * - 12 -> number of cols  (grid unit).
  * - 75px -> row height    (px)
  */
  background-size: calc(((100% - 10px) / 12)) 75px;
}
```

And this is the result, the grid fit perfectly for me.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I went through `codesandbox` you provided.
You forgot to import your css file in `index.js`.
Add this line add the end of the import section in `index.js`

```
import './styles.css';
```

Comment: i imported it in showcaselayout.js, u should be able to see the grids..

Comment: I am not able to see it in this file as well as `showcaselayout.js`.

Comment: I have edited my question and post a screenshot of where I import it. able to see it?